# How to access a node server from pc on local network

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

So I'm hosting a node server on a ubuntu pc, lets call this PC A and on my Windows 10 PC, lets call it PC B I'm trying to connect to it, if I try connection on PC A by inputting 127.0.0.1:8000 into the browser it works fine but on PC B if I input (PC A IP):8000 (PC A IP is the ip of the PC A on my local network I got through using ifconfig in console) PC B cant connect to the server, the server is the base http.createServer code on Nodes official site here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener

I'v also tried a using a different port such as 8080, 8090

Comment: Iv also tried chaning .listen to server.listen(3000, '(COMPUTER A IP)')

Comment: Are you certain the machines can communicate over the network and there isn't a firewall or something preventing them from doing so? Are you certain the localhost post on the windows machine is set up to allow external traffic?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the IP representing `localhost`, which is an address accessible only by the PC on which the server is running (PC A in your case). Check on which IP is the server running. If you want it to be accessible by other PCs on your local network, find out the local IP of the PC on which you're trying to run the server (PC A) and specify that IP the configuration of the NodeJS server. You can find out the local IP on Linux using `ip addr` command in a terminal.

Comment: I forgot i had a firewall running blocking connections, sorry, but thanks for the replies.